# How to validate response assertion with XML elements?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How to validate response assertion with  XML elements see below http response example?

Is this correct?
[image]

[image: Response Data in jemeter]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [XPath Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion) would be a better match for XML data, the relevant XPath expression to check whether `sampledUrl` node text is equal to `http://abc.com/off/paul.html` will be:

```
//sampledUrl/text()='http://abc.com/off/paul.html'
```

[image: JMeter XPath Assertion Example]

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on conditionally failing JMeter samplers with different types of assertions.

Comment: is it possible to add two Xpath assertions and two response assertions?

Comment: as many as you need, but remember that assertions has their cost so try to limit their usage to only those which are absolutely required